# How to add Drag and Drop over SWT CommonNavigator

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have a CommonNavigator view and unable to add drag and drop support on it by tradition way of addDrag&Dropsupport method.
I want to drop some files from File Systen over the CommonNavigator.
After searching I found , I just needed to hook the dropAgent and it will work. So I did like following-
       point="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.navigatorContent">

```
  <navigatorContent
        contentProvider="com.infineon.stt.session.explorer.ui.SessionContentProvider"
        id="com.infineon.stt.session.explorer.ui.navigatorContent"
        labelProvider="com.infineon.stt.session.explorer.ui.SessionLabelProvider"
        name="Session Navigation Content">             
     <dropAssistant
          class="com.infineon.stt.session.explorer.ui.ResourceDropAdapterAssistant"
          id="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.resourceDropAdapter">
       <possibleDropTargets>
          <or>
             <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject"/>
             <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFolder"/>
             <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile"/>
             <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IWorkspaceRoot"/>
          </or>
       </possibleDropTargets>
    </dropAssistant> 
     <triggerPoints>
        <instanceof
              value="com.infineon.stt.session.model.SessionRoot">
        </instanceof>
       </triggerPoints>

  </navigatorContent>
```

But even it didn't work.
Any suggestion to make the scenario work.
I followed up this example-
https://github.com/aptana/studio3/blob/4cada2cfef2969d11bd62fcce7d630a05b6cab64/plugins/com.aptana.explorer/plugin.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was very simple.
I was committing a mistake of restricting the drag and drop to specific type.
To allow any kind if Object , I just need to pass **possibledroptarget** as object-

```
   <possibleDropTargets>
      <or>
         <adapt type="java.lang.Object"/>
      </or>
   </possibleDropTargets>
```